# Textarea disabled return to the page previous

Tags: html, textarea

I wanted to prevent access to my textarea and for that, I insert the "disabled" attribute in my textarea but when I select the text inside it to remove my naviguator return to the page previous ...

Try it yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/Uqrnm/1/

```
<textarea disabled> MyTextarea </textarea>
```

1. Select the text
2. Try removing
3. WTF ?

Thank's

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me in Chrome. And in FF I can't even select it.

Comment: @j08691 Try not opening the link in a new tab, but in the current tab, creating browser history.

Comment: @kapa - ah yes. Although now I see the behavior in Chrome but FF is still fine.

Comment: @j08691 Hm, I can't even select the text in FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key you are trying to use is a hotkey for *Back* in most browsers.

Since your element is `disabled`, it does not receive focus, so pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key will trigger the *Back* functionality of the browser tab (at least in IE and Chrome, but Firefox does not even let me select the text).

So there is no WTF, this is quite normal behaviour.